# NSURL returning nil with Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3, nsurl

While running this code with Swift 2.3, it was fine. When I started to update my code for Swift 3, the problem started. My `NSURL` returns zero when I use the below code:

```
{

var searchResults: [String]!

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let correctedAddress = self.searchResults[indexPath.row].addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)        
let urlpath:NSString! = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(correctedAddress)" as NSString!
let url = NSURL.init(string: urlpath as String)
```

}

```
 }
```

I am very new to iOS programming, so my question may be very basic. I have Googled a lot but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift there is lot of changes in the syntax, You can make your URL like this:-

```
let correctedAddress = "Delhi " //You can replace your address here
let urlpath = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(correctedAddress)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
let url = URL(string: urlpath!)
print(url!)
```

Result:- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Delhi%20